# Show $\big\lvert\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}e^{-i2\pi f}\big\vert^{2} = \sin^2(\pi f)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

$\big\lvert\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}e^{-i2\pi f}\big\vert^{2} = \sin^2(\pi f)$?

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! By sharing your thoughts on the problem, you will better enable other users to answer your question. So, to that end, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Write this as

$${1\over 4}\left|e^{\pi if}-e^{-\pi i f}\right|^2.$$

They're equal since $|e^{i\theta}|=1$ for all $\theta$. (in this case we put in a factor of $|e^{i\pi f}|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Assuming $f\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\left|\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}e^{-2i\pi f}\right|^{2} = \sin^2(\pi f)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|\frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-2i\pi f}\right)\right|^{2} = \sin^2(\pi f)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\left|1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-2i\pi f}\right|^{2} = \sin^2(\pi f)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2\pi f)+\left(-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\pi f)-1\right)^2}\right)^{2} = \sin^2(\pi f)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2\pi f)+\left(-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\pi f)-1\right)^2\right)= \sin^2(\pi f)$$